# Member for - how Drupal 7 calculaties and formats duration?

Tags: views, datetime

Drupal 7 has ability to show since how long someone is member, like this:

> Member for 2 months 21 hours

What date field it uses to save the registration date/time?
How it calculates and displays this duration? And can't we use same module / method to calculate duration from our date (in node) and display in our views?

I am really in need of this functionality of calculating of duration, I am using views Calc and subtracting end-date from start-date and dividing it with number of seconds in day to get number of days between two days. but not satisfy besides don't know why can't subtract `now()` from a given date field in views calculations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$account->content['summary']['member_for'] = array(
  '#type' => 'user_profile_item',
  '#title' => t('Member for'),
  '#markup' => format_interval(REQUEST_TIME - $account->created),
);
```

It's in [`function user_user_view($account)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_user_view/7). And yes, of course you can use [`format_interval($interval)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_interval/7) function in other places.

Comment: I just discover it is very simple if one has to display the duration between a given date and today with "Time ago" Display of the date in views. it display member since xx year xx month etc. I would love to use it but have two problems, 
1. cannot use filter on this i.e. member more than 4 years or member since 5 year etc. 
2. I cannot do calculation on it i.e. 4 Years + duration2 = total duration.  
On other hand in views calc now() - date is not working and giving error that now value not allowed here.
just looked at format_interval seems good but may not work with views calc.

Comment: Thanks Molot and Gisle format_interval() work great. I am still struggling with calculated column for different duration and their total, but have learn so many things in last months.